# Find marginal density function from joint density function

Tags: probability-distributions

If I have a joint density function for X and Y:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\pi x \cos(\frac {\pi y} 2)  & 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}  \\
\end{cases}$

How do I find the marginal density function for X?

I think I need to integrate $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ over $dy$ but what do I integrate it from? Should it be 0 and 1 or 0 and x or x and 0? I've looked over a lot of examples with different domains but I can't figure out their method in getting the range for integration. They always skip that step in the working because apparently it should be obvious, but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: From zero to one.

Comment: In principal you integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, but since the joint density vanishes outside the interval $0\le y \le 1$, it is sufficient to integrate from $0$ to $1$, as Eckhard pointed out correctly.

Comment: What would be the integral limit if condition was $0 \lt x \lt y \lt 1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The marginal density is given by
$$
f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Now, this equals
$$
\int_{0}^1 \pi x\cos\left(\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)\,\mathrm dy,\quad \text{if }\;0\leq x\leq 1
$$
and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Why is the lower integration limit -1 instead of 0?

Comment: @Matt: Was a typo, thanks

Comment: +1. And, since $f_X(x)=cx\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x\leqslant1}$, one sees that $c=2$ without even computing the $y$-integral.